# Non-GUI Automated System Test Framework

Tags: python, frameworks, automated-tests, system-testing

I am looking for an automated test framework for testing a system with the following characteristics:

```
 1. Non-GUI System
 2. Has backend nodes running on multiple Linux/Unix hosts
 3. Has remotely executing processes against which we must test
 4. Results in a lot of DB access.
```

The testing performed is system/integration/acceptance testing, not unit testing. Am language agnostic with respect to the framework. Any language/technology, as long as the system fits the bill, is welcome (although python will be preferred :) ).

an example scenario:
I want to compare two versions of a product functionally.

```
    1. V1 will run on machine 1. The results will be written to database X
    2. V2 will run on machine 2. The results will be written to database Y
    3. The table structures of V1 & V2 are very different but logically same.
    4. Same data will be pushed to machine 1 & machine 2
```

Comment: Is this a Service Oriented Architecture? Do you have an API or APIs through which you can test? Trying to get a handle on the architecture and what the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Its not a service oriented architecture. It has multithreaded processes like that of backend of Banking, Telecom sector.

Answer (score 2):

Try Pysys: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pysys/

We use it where I work for system testing and it's pretty good. Very flexible.